# Bulletproof "back to top" anchor that works with base href?

Tags: php, html, anchor

How can I create a bulletproof "Back to top" anchor that works regardless of whether the site has a base href or not?

Should I use script to sniff the current URL of the page and dynamically create the anchor?

Anchor at the top of the page is:

```
<a id="top"></a>
```

"Back to top" link is at the bottom of the page:

```
<a href="#top">Back to top</a>
```

However, when there is a base href present on the page, regardless of the current directory, the "back to top" always resolves to the base href. How can I overcome that?

Comment: `<p>To go pack to top, press Home on your keyboard.</p>`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it server side with this PHP:

```
return '<a href="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'#top">&uarr; Back to Top</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in the past, but it's Javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- 
document.write("<a href= \"" + document.location + "#top\">top</a>"); 
// --> 
</script>
```